# Phrase help for do's and don'ts

Tags: word-choice, phrases

While I am writing some health tips, I used a phrase do's and don'ts, in describing my activities. I wonder, if there is any equivalent word to do's and don'ts. I believe this phrase is archaic. Are there any phrases that can be used in place of them.

**Update:**
Here's the context where I am using

Do's

- Sleep early and wake up early

Don'ts

- Keep away from brewed beverages

Comment: I think it may help to give more details about the context. Friendly, conversational style? Formal style? Would *Recommendations* work?

Comment: I would recommend leaving off the gratuitous apostrophes: "dos and don'ts". [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%27s+and+don%27t%27s%2Cdos+and+don%27ts%2Cdo%27s+and+don%27ts&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) doesn't seem to think it's archaic.

Comment: It is not archaic, and it's used all the time, at least in the U.S. @PeterShor is correct about the apostrophes, btw.

Comment: Surely "Keep away from brewed beverages" is a "Do", if that's what you want people to do. It looks like my "Recommendations" might be just what you want!

Comment: @PeterShor: The apostrophe allowed in do's is one of the very few with which one can wallop the you-must-never-use-an-apostrophe-in-a-pure-plural brigade! On a more reasonable level, _dos_ (not the OS), _hairdos_ and _exs_ look weirder than the alternatives to my eye.

Comment: @Robusto: Not archaic, obsolescent or overly informal in the UK either.

Comment: (as an aside, I note that this question -- which is entirely about apostrophes, since the phrase itself, however spelt, is surely a common idiom -- has the tags `word-choice` and `phrases`; I offer this as one example of the irrelevance of the tag system. Not to mention the difficulty of finding a reasonable answer for a question, and the difficulty of asking a reasonable question in the first place.)

Comment: _Dos_ and _Don’ts_ could be misread. It’s one of the cases where the apostrophe can be reasonably used to indicate the plural. If you do use it, be consistent: _Do’s_ and _Don’t’s_.

Comment: I don't think that don'ts is easily misread, so I'd use do's and don'ts (and maybes).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. It could be an abbreviation of _doughnuts_.

Comment: I see nothing constructive about this question, which seems entirely predicated on OP's mistaken belief that *Do's and Don'ts* is "archaic".

Comment: You could just call the whole thing: *Rules to live by*

Comment: @Barrie England. I bet that doesn't stop you using _don't_. Anyway, donuts should have jam in the middle.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. That's what the apostrophe stands for - the missing jam.

Comment: Please edit the question to cite reliable sources supporting your beliefs. We try to rely on facts so that the site does not degenerate into opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Do's and Don'ts" is perfectly acceptable and does not feel archaic to a US English native speaker. You will probably hear it every day on national TV in exactly this kind of context -- health tips, financial advice, etc.

What you might be sensing about this phrase is that it is somewhat informal, rather than archaic. It is unusual to use "do" and "don't" as nouns. It's pretty much restricted to this phrase, in fact! And my experience suggests that a word acting as a rare part of speech is frequently a sign of archaic usage.

Answer (score 2):

"Best Practices" might be the term used in business communication, meaning essentially the same thing as "Dos and Donts".

Answer (score -1):

***"Tips and Tricks"*** is a more recent version which is not exactly the same as "do's and don't's".

If the list is just going to be very brief bullet point items, just ***"Tips"*** or ***"Health Tips"***, for example, would be appropriate.

***"Tricks"*** would be used for more detailed suggestions such as "If you rinse your apple slices with lemon juice, they won't turn brown."

Comment: Would downvoter please leave some feedback?